# Is it possible to convert a python script into an exe (pyinstaller, etc.) and then call that exe from C++ and pass it variables in a function?

Tags: python, c++, dll

I know you can call python scripts from c++ but Ive also been told you cant run python on computers without having it installed. The way around that is to pack it into an exe using py2exe or pyinstaller and the like, and run it that way.  But I need to pass information to that script from c++.  Im limited to c++ due to the program that I'm trying to write a .dll for (ZBrush), and want to pass it around to people without them needing to install python on their computer.

In the program I'm going to press a button that will call the .dll and pass it a variable, then run the python exe, then run the script with the variable from the dll passed to it.

Is that even possible to do?

Comment: You can pass command-line arguments or stdin to a .exe the same way you can to a script. But you can't call a function from Python code inside the .exe. If you really need to do that, you need to embed a Python interpreter in your C++ app. Which is often a useful thing to do, but it's a non-trivial amount of work, especially the first time.

Comment: So, the easy way is to reorganize your Python code so that the function you want to call is the "entry point"—the top-level script code calls that function with sys.argv and/or stdin, and then outputs its result to stdout. If you're using `setuptools`, it can actually do most of the work for you. I think [this](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) is the docs section you want, but read it and see.